# Is there a simple way of limiting QObject::findChild() to direct children only?

Tags: qt, qobject

Question is in the title.  I can't find anything obvious in [the documentation](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html) which suggests a way of doing this.  Must I use the recursive children finding methods and test each child's parent pointer sequentially to filter out the non-direct children?

Incidentally, the documentation seems to refer to "direct ancestor"s by which I think it means "direct descendant".

(edit: I'm looking for simplicity, so the answer doesn't have to use the `findChild()` method.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have [added](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/merge_requests/40) a flag to [QObject::findChild()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#findChild) in Qt 5, called `Qt::FindDirectChildOnly`, which allows you to do exactly this.

So this issue will soon be a problem of the past :-)

Comment: You're a star :) Do you have a link to the change request?

Answer (score 5):

```
template <class T>
T findDirectChild(const QObject* parent, const QString& name = QString())
{
    foreach (QObject* child, parent->children())
    {
        T temp = qobject_cast<T>(child);
        if (temp && (name.isNull() || name == child->objectName()))
            return temp;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A template version that will filter based on type with optional name.
Based on answer by TheHorse.

Answer (score 0):

```
QObject* find(QObject* parent, const QString& objName)
{
    foreach (QObject* child, parent->children())
    {
        if (child->objectName() == objName)
        {
            return child;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Certainly an answer (so thank you) but I'd prefer not to rely on the `objectName` being set.  It could easily produce false positives if parent and child haven't had their name set.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the answer given by skyhisi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8744496/594137) the exact answer would be implemented as follows, which more closely meets my needs.

```
ChildClass const * ParentClass::_getPointerToDirectChild() const
{
    QObjectList allDirectChildren = this->children();
    QObject * anObject = 0;
    ChildClass const * aChild = 0;

    while (allDirectChildren.isEmpty() == false)
    {
        anObject = allDirectChildren.takeFirst();
        aChild = qobject_cast<ChildClass *>(anObject);
        if (aChild) return aChild;
    }

    return aChild;
}
```

Comment: Emptying a container with takeFirst() in the loop, is a very slow solution. Prefer const iteration when possible, as is definitely the case here.

Comment: Agreed for performance I wouldn't use this, but I would argue that's premature optimisation and I clearly stated "I'm looking for simplicity" :)

Comment: A const iteration isn't any more complex than this (it's actually simpler), and I would argue that doing something properly isn't premature optimization when there's a clear guideline for a "good" and "bad" way of doing it.  Unless this is a one-off project, that's exactly the kind of thing that will come back to bite you.